# How to get applicationId after all suffixes added in android app/build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, applicationid

How to get applicationId after all suffixes added in android **app/build.gradle**

I tried to use it as below, but the application id is null, we are setting the applicationId to default config from **app/build.gradle**, I assume it has executed later than we set the resValue, also I need the applicationId when it is completely appended with all suffix from flavor and buildType.

**app/build.gradle**

```
android {
     defaultConfig.applicationId "com.companyname.appname"
}
```

**util/build.gradle**

```
android {
     defaultConfig {
         resValue "string", "freshchat_file_provider_authority", applicationId + ".provider"
     }
}
```

Share if anybody can support about this.

Answer (score 1):

We can make applicationId via accessing current **flavorName** and **buildType** by placing the below code in **app/build.gradle** android closure as below.

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavorName = variant.flavorName
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        def applicationIdMade = defaultConfig.applicationId + ".$flavorName.$buildType"
        println applicationIdMade // Use as you require
    }
```